# Creating dynamic ids for jquery Carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel

```
<div id="container_01">
    <div class="pikachoose">
        <ul id="pikame" class="jcarousel-skin-pika">
            <li>
                <img id="main_photo" name="main_photo" src="image.jpg" width="520" height="380" class="delayLoad" border="0"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
   </div>     
</div>
```

Since there are many carousel divs on one page, only the first div displays correctly, and remain fail.

How do I create multiple carousels on the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs are unique to the page; however, classes can be used any number of times.

You can use the following snippet to target every element with the class name "foo"  for example.

```
$('.foo').each(function(){
 //dosomething
});
```

Comment: thank you @ good4m. Solved the problem with class instead of ID

Answer (score 0):

Use Latest jcaraousel.min.js

Read this Link
http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

for full documenetation. use their Property well.

Thanks